# Monitoring Internet data from modem

Tags: networking, router, modem, bandwidth, qos

I'm about to get a new ADSL internet connection and the data available is split between me and two other housemates.

As I am going to be the administrator, I was wondering if there is any way to monitor the usage of each person from my own computer.

I've read about [QoS](http://www.squidoo.com/bandwidth-management) but it only helps in setting bandwidth limitations for programs such as BitTorrent. And my [modem](http://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=1194) is definitely capable of QoS.

Can I use the QoS feature to set limitations using IP addresses? If not, what other alternative features can enable me to do this?

Comment: Can I ask what benefit you are hoping to achieve?  Are you looking to split costs by consumption... Or perhaps throttle to prevent bandwidth-hogging?

Comment: using tc on linux, you can put the traffic into buckets but then not throttle the bucket, and check the bucket traffic counts to work out the usage.

Comment: @BrianAdkins Yes primarily splitting costs by consumption.

Comment: @Sirex Could you provide any links on how that works?

Comment: It's not important that i 'Control' the data. If i can monitor the individual usage, that's good enough so i can warn my housemates if they are going to exceed their usage limit

Comment: i'll have a look and see if i can dig anything up (prolly not). I used to use it (tc) on linux a few years ago. I actually throttled the traffic types, but the side effectof using tc was the ability to see how much traffic had gone into each traffic type. Look into tc.

Comment: What's going to route the traffic to the ASDL connection? a dedicated router? your own machine?

Comment: @PatriceLevesque This (http://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=1194) is what i have

Comment: Mmm so your device is the router.  So, to measure the bandwith, you either have to make each machine count its outgoing traffic (hence you have to trust your roommates don't cheat) or put a box in front of the modem, could be an old recycled computer or a dedicated router; what are your thoughts?

Comment: @PatriceLevesque I'm not sure how a dedicated box connected to the device would help me monitor the usage. If it's possible, i wouldn't mind hooking up my own laptop to it. Although it wouldn't be a 'dedicated' box then :)

Comment: In a dedicated box scenario, that box would pre-route all traffic, acting as a gateway, so it would measure bandwidth.  That is, if none of your roommates hook cables directly to your modem or access it via WiFi.  Thinking about that scenario, it seems more and more that your problem cannot be solved for any half-savvy roommate if he wants to cheat, unless you physically lock the modem and turn of its wifi, and essentially re-implement what your modem already does with other hardware, just to add metering ;)

Comment: @PatriceLevesque Hmm i see what you mean about the dedicated box. IT's worth a try if i can get a spare computer. For now i guess i'll have to settle with setting limits on bittorrent and such using QoS.

Comment: If they're going to be wired, you might be able to use `snmp` to track usage on their respective ethernet ports, but this doesn't work if they're going to be using a wifi port.  (and if you're going to have wifi, how're you going to deal with accounting for guest access?)

Comment: I used a tiny intel box running ubuntu server to monitor all the traffic from various devices at home. see http://www.diyweb.lk/?p=159 for details. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NetWorx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) on my home network for bandwidth monitoring. It can log data directly from the router using SNMP or UPnP.

The caveat is that you need to keep your monitoring PC switched on and monitoring traffic 24/7 [because the router resets its upload and download counters every 4 GB](https://www.softperfect.com/board/read.php?8,10845,20619#msg-20619).

While this lets you know what your total bandwidth consumption is, it won't let you distinguish your data usage from your housemates' usage.

As @NevinWilliams mentioned in the comments, if you're not going to be using Wi-Fi, you can measure the traffic of individual network interfaces using SNMP. NetWorx can do that but you may need to run it on separate computers to monitor their individual LAN interfaces.

[image: NetWorx monitor router LAN interface using SNMP]

You could have each of your housemates install and run NetWorx to monitor their individual traffic, but this boils down to whether or not you trust them to diligently monitor their internet traffic and not cheat.

Alternatively, you can install [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/site/) on your router and set up a [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) server to manage authentication and accounting. This is advanced stuff but you can find guides on the Internet and various forums and figure out how to do this.

If you'd rather not go through the trouble of setting all of that up, your best bet is to use a hotspot service like [HotspotSystem](http://www.hotspotsystem.com/) to manage bandwidth. They have a few free plans but you're going to have to flash [either DD-WRT](http://www.hotspotsystem.com/installation-guide-dd-wrt) [or OpenWRT](http://www.hotspotsystem.com/openwrt-hotspot-setup) custom router firmware on a supported router.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a kind of "firewall" (or router) upstream of the router/modem.
This would work with any motherboard that has 3 network interfaces, or you could use a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) and buy two [USB-RJ45 adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BCVUIIU).

*(The Rasbperry Pi solution would be my favorite, as these devices require very little power in continuous operation)*

You can install a normal Linux on the Raspberry Pi (the [RPI imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) is suitable for this)

When the Pi is running, simply set up [forwarding rules using IP tables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface), e.g. that all traffic from `interface A` *(your neighbor)* and `interface B` *(you)* should be forwarded to `interface C`*(where your router/modem is connected)*.

There are great Grafana projects for Raspberry Pis.

There you can [visualize](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13982-raspberry-pi-monitoring/) the bandwidth per network interface.
To do this, you need to install [Telegraf, InfluxDB and Grafana](https://www.mm218.dev/posts/2020/05/).

Don't worry, it all sounds terribly complicated, but in the end it's not at all (and it's also a bit of fun)

Another advantage would be that you could also implement a few security features in this way. For example, you could prohibit traffic from being routed from `interface A` (your neighbor) to `interface B` (you).